# Undefined function or variable 'w'

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to solve an ODE for a school project, and I'm running into a problem with one variable. Wondering if I could get some help.
I'm using ODE15s solver.

```
options = odeset('RelTol',2.22045e-14, 'AbsTol', 1e-6);
[T,Y] = ode15s(@odeHMCase5,[0,200],[4.3,5.1,3,0,422],options);
```

The variable in question is part of a block of conditional statements, when debugging it does show up in the workspace.

```
%define G as a global variable
global G

%Define ec
if z(5) < 453
    ec = 0;
else
    ec = 1;
end

if (ec == 1) & (G == false)
    G = true;
elseif (ec == 1) & (G == true)
    G = true;
elseif (ec == 0) & (G == true)
    G = true;
elseif (ec == 0) & (G == false)
    G = false;
end

if G == false
    w = 0;
elseif (G == true) & (z(5) >= 433)
    w = 1;
elseif (G == true) & (z(5) < 433)
    w = 0;
    G = false;
end
```

In addition the conditional operators &&, when running, MATLAB throws up this error ,

```
Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.
```

Changing to & seems to be the only way around it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please display the **full error**, specifically what line it's occurring at.  Also please provide the full implementation of `odeHMCase5`.  If it's simply the addition of the function signature then do that.  Also because `G` is global, it would help if you told us what exactly that is and how you're setting it.  Also, we don't know what `z` is supposed to be.  When you post a question, the error is supposed to be reproducible.  Your question is not so.  Also please see [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem ("`Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.`") is pretty easy to solve. In the scope of `if` statement conditions, you must use the double logical operators (`&&` or `||`):

```
if (ec == 1) & (G == false)  % WRONG
if (ec == 1) && (G == false) % CORRECT
```

The undefined variable `w` error is due to the fact that your last `if` statement ends with an `elseif` and no `else` clause is defined. Therefore, when none of the specified conditions is evaluated to `true`, no value is assigned variable `w`:

```
if G == false % THIS CAN ALSO BE REWRITTEN AS: if (~G)
    w = 0;
elseif (G == true) && (z(5) >= 433) % FIX THE LOGICAL OPERATOR
    w = 1;
elseif (G == true) && (z(5) < 433) % FIX THE LOGICAL OPERATOR
    w = 0;
    G = false;
else
    w = ?; % WRITE SOMETHING HERE
end
```

The statement above could be also simplified as follows, and this should fix the issue unless I misunderstood what you're trying to accomplish:

```
if (G)
    if (z(5) >= 433)
        w = 1;
    else
        w = 0;
        G = false;
    end
else
    w = 0;
end
```